# Unable to get a mapping value

Tags: mapping, solidity

I'm trying to implement a small contract to upload file hashes on the blockchain along with the file description and the sender address. I've programmed this small contract :

```
pragma solidity^0.4.17;


contract hashes {
    mapping(uint => string) descriptions;
    mapping(uint => address) senderAddresses;


function uploadHash(uint _hash, string _description) public {
    require(bytes(descriptions[_hash]).length == 0);
    descriptions[_hash] = _description;
    senderAddresses[_hash] = msg.sender;
}

function getHash(uint _hash) public returns (address, string){
    return (senderAddresses[_hash], descriptions[_hash]);
}
```

}

I think uploadHash works as expected since when I'm uploading the same hash twice I get a revert. However when I'm trying to use getHash, I don't get any return value. The results are the same when I'm calling from remix or directly from web3.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Remix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the view modifier

```
function getHash(uint _hash) public view returns (address, string)
```

Remix will not show the res next to the input boxes unless you use the view modifier.